# I need to compare two very large collections with potentially missing elements

Tags: c#, linq

I've come across a brick wall in a program I am writing for my work.
You don't need to know the context specifically, but long story short, I have two collections of around ~650k records each.

Let's assume that collection A is the one I know is correct, and collection B is the one I know is incorrect.

Collection B contains a complex object, which has a Property of the same type as the elements in Collection A (in other words, it looks like a bit like this):

```
// Where T : IComparable
IEnumerable<DateTime> A = ...; // Collection of T elements
IEnumerable<Complex> B = ...; // Collection of complex elements.
class Complex<DateTime>
{
   public DateTime Time { get; set; }
   .....
}
```

My issue is that I basically need to sequentially enumerate over A and see if the current element of A exists in a Complex object in B; if it doesn't exist, then I need to create a Complex object which will encapsulate that element (amongst other things).

The problem occurs when I realize that both lists are 650,000 elements long, approx. I can't reduce the data set down; I have to use these 650,000. Right now I've used `ICollection.Contains()`, and I tried a (naive) implementation of Binary Search, but it just takes far too long.

Have you got any suggestions for me?

EDIT: If it helps, T implements IComparable.
EDIT2: Some more context:
The IEnumerable is retrieved from a DataTable using Linq To Objects.

```
        IEnumerable<Complex> set = set.Tbl
            .Where(dbObject => dbObject.TS.CompareTo(default(DateTime)) != 0)
            .Select(Func<DataRow,Complex>) // Function that wraps the DataRow in a Complex object
            // Just done to make debugging a little easier so we still have a large sample but small enough that it doesn't make me grow a beard
            .Take(100000) 
            .AsEnumerable<Complex>();
```

For sake of completeness in case this question gets archived and anyone else needs to sovle this issue, my current implementation looked a bit like this

```
        BDataSet bSet = new BDataSet();
        B_LUTableAdapter adap = new B_LUTableAdapter();
        adap.Fill(bSet.B_LU);
        IEnumerable<Complex> w3 = bSet.B
            .Where(dbObject => dbObject.TS.CompareTo(default(DateTime)) != 0)
            // Function that just wraps datarow into a complex object
            .Select(Func<DataRow, Complex>)
            // Just for sake of debugging speed
            .Take(100000)
            .AsEnumerable<Complex>();

        List<Complex> b = bSet.OrderBy(x => x.Time).ToList<Complex>();
        // Get last & first timestamps
        // Some of the timestamps in b are 01/01/1011 for some reason,
        // So we do this check.
        Complex start = b.Where(x => x.Time != default(DateTime)).First();
        Complex end = b.Last();

        List<DateTime> a = new List<DateTime>();
        // RoundSeconds reduces seconds in a DateTime to 0.
        DateTime current = RoundSeconds(new DateTime(start.Time.Ticks));

        while (current.CompareTo(RoundSeconds(end.Time)) <= 0)
        {
            a.Add(current);
            current = current.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        }

        IEnumerable<DateTime> times = b.Select(x => x.Time);
        var missing = a.Where(dt => times.Contains(dt));
        foreach (var dt in missing)
        {
            adap.Insert(dt, 0, "", "", "", null, 0, 0);
            // This has since been changed to List.Add()
        }
```

Thanks to Cosmin this issue is now resolved, and the finished implementation is this:
            List expected = new List();
            DateTime current = RoundSeconds(new DateTime(start.Time.Ticks));

```
        while (current.CompareTo(RoundSeconds(end.Time)) <= 0)
        {
            expected.Add(current);
            current = current.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Expecting {0} intervals.", expected.Count);
        var missing = b.FindAllMissing(expected, x => x.Time);
        if(!missing.Any()) return;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} missing intervals.", missing.Count());
        foreach (var dt in missing)
        {
            b.Add(new Complex() { /* some values */ });
            //Console.WriteLine("\t> Inserted new record at {0}", dt);
        }

        //.....
        public static IEnumerable<Basic> FindAllMissing<Basic, Complex>(this IEnumerable<Complex> complexList,
        IEnumerable<Basic> basicList,
        Func<Complex, Basic> selector)
        {
            HashSet<Basic> inComplexList = new HashSet<Basic>();
            foreach (Complex c in complexList)
                inComplexList.Add(selector(c));
            List<Basic> missing = new List<Basic>();
            foreach (Basic basic in basicList)
                if (!(inComplexList.Contains(basic)))
                    missing.Add(basic);
            return missing;
        }
```

Comment: You could try indexing your collection B with a Lookup by A first. And then you could try to parallelize it using `.AsParallel()`. And measure the effect of both.

Comment: You could use a `HashSet<T>` for faster lookups.

Comment: you selected 'linq' as a tag, but I don't see linq.

Comment: @ps2goat: Fixed that for you. :)

Comment: Are the elements of A and the elements of B both ordered the same? If so, it is a O(n) algorithm to iterate over A looking for missing B's.

Comment: Do A and B come from the same database?  Or is this all in-memory, in-file, etc.?

Comment: The DataSet seems a long and slow detour.

Comment: Begs the question, how often is this operation to occur? And how long is too long?

Comment: Are these 2 files ordered by the same criteria?

Comment: @PhillipNgan They are ordered in terms of T comparable, however I cannot guarentee that B has all the elemenets that A has.

Comment: @ps2goat B is from a database, A is generated based on timestamps from B (DateTime is the T)

Comment: @Paul Zahra Well I need the data within today if possible as a colleague is relying on it for a presentation within the next week. Its' a bespoke solution for one of our clients, so not often but it would be useful to keep the procedure as our company deals with a _lot_ of data.

Comment: @Henk Holterman Not my choice, the original data is in Access form

Comment: @Silvermind They are both ordered by DateTime (MyComplex). I'll update original answer to clarify

Comment: If You are concerned about performance remove the `.AsEnumerable<Complex>();` from Your query. This will execute Your query immediately. I guess `Linq` uses **yield return** if possible when iterating over collections, so if You remove `.AsEnumerable<Complex>();`, when iterating over Your collection items will be loaded into memory and processed one item at a time.  

This suggestion will not have any sense if the collections are already loaded into memory. Can You rewrite Your code so that Your query will work with the exact data source? Use Entity Framework for example.

Comment: @AleksiChepovoi: I used AsEnumerable because I iterate over the set several times, which if I didn't put the collection into memory,w ould cause the query to have to be executed several times (if I understand D.E correctly). Also as this is a program that essentially performs one purpose, I deemed it unsuitable to use EF (which in hindsight makes me feel stupid)

Comment: Also I should mention it's not a factor that "ooh it might not be as fast as it could be"; more along the lines of in it's original state it was prohibitively slow.

Comment: If this two files have the same criteria you could also iterate through every line and check if the lines at that index match, if not you would increment the index of one file until the lines match. If you have this possibility, the main advantage is that you can reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step-by-step:

- Use one of the `O(1)` generic collections to create a fast-searchable list of `T`'s that are already in the second collection. May I suggest `HashSet<T>`
- Enumerate over the SECOND collection and put all the `T`'s in the collection from the first step.
- Enumerate of the FIRST collection and check if each item is in the collection created at step one. Since that operation is `O(1)` you've now got a `O(n)` solution.
- Enjoy.

---

Here's a class that implements that algorithm as a generic extension method, to make it extra LINQ-friendly. Made take it's arguments as `IEnumerable<T>` and return `IEnumerable<T>`, made no assumptions about the types (`T` and `Complex`). In my test I'm using a list of `Tuple<int,int>` as a complex type and a simple `int` as the simple type. The console application fills the `List<Tuple<int,int>>` with 600000 values, then puts 100000 values in the simple `List<int>` that uses an enumerator to count all the simple values that are not found in the `List<Tuple<int,int>>`; It's so fast you don't get a chance to see it doing it's work, when you hit `F5` it just shows the result.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{

    static class FixProblem
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> FindAllThatNeedCreating<T, Complex>(this IEnumerable<Complex> list_of_complex, IEnumerable<T> list_of_T, Func<Complex, T> extract)
        {
            HashSet<T> T_in_list_of_complex = new HashSet<T>();
            foreach (Complex c in list_of_complex)
                T_in_list_of_complex.Add(extract(c));
            List<T> answer = new List<T>();
            foreach (T t in list_of_T)
                if (!T_in_list_of_complex.Contains(t))
                    answer.Add(t);
            return answer;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Test the code
            List<Tuple<int, int>> complex = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            List<int> simple = new List<int>();

            // Fill in some random data
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i < 600000; i++)
                complex.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(rnd.Next(), rnd.Next()));

            for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
                simple.Add(rnd.Next());

            // This is the magic line of code:
            Console.WriteLine(complex.FindAllThatNeedCreating(simple, x => x.Item1).Count());

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did go down this road, but when I tried doing `new HashSet(myEnumerable)`, again, it took way too much time. I think I need to elaborate on my original question with some context.

Comment: Try again: look at my code, 600k "complex" records and 100k "simple" records, when you hit run you get the result, no time to "time" it. It really is a `O(n)` algorithm.

Comment: My code here has two interesting guarantees: It enumerates the whole `complex` list *exactly once* and then enumerates the simple list *exactly once*. If this is slow for your data then the enumeration itself is slow, it's not the algorithm's fault and magic needs to be spent speeding up the base enumeration, not this algorithm.

Comment: I am currently trying an implementation of your algorithm simply because as an extension method it'll be easy to re-use and pass around. However, I have an issue - It seems to add every DateTime to the "answer" list. See my implementation on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/LmDYYpJU)

Comment: I just checked, `DateTime` properly implements `GetHashCode()` (the only requirement of the code above) so your problem lies elsewhere. Maybe your dates are almost equal but not equal (example: one has a time, the other has a different time, etc). Here's the code above made to work with `DateTime`, play with it: http://pastebin.com/z2YDst7U

Comment: Yeah, I'll double check, although I rounded everything down to minute intervals. EDIT: didnt' with the raw data. Thank you! Accepting this answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing your complex objects in a Dictionary, using the A-type property as the key. Then you can see if any element in A exists in the Dictionary very quickly. Each lookup operation will be O(1), and the overall performance should be O(n).

Alternatively, you could call .ToLookup() on your existing IEnumerable, and create the key and value in a lambda expression. The returned ILookup should be perfect for your needs (i.e. looking up values from A). The additional advantage here is that if you have multiple complex objects containing A, you'll get a collection of them back when you use the Lookup.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: First of all, stop using the datasets. I suggest you use Linq to SQL or Entity Framework.

Try this:

```
        var lookup = B.ToLookup(c => c.MyComplex);

        var noMatch = from a in A
                      where !lookup.Contains(a)
                      select a;
```

That *should* be faster, but measure.

Then try

```
        var lookup = B.AsParallel().ToLookup(c => c.MyComplex);

        var noMatch = from a in A.AsParallel()
                      where !lookup.Contains(a)
                      select a;
```

And measure again.

Obviously, make sure that the type of the objects in A overrides `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object)` correclty and efficiently. Especially `GetHashCode()` should have a high probability that different objects have a different hash code, and still be fast.

UPDATE: Since we now know that the type of the objects in A is DateTime, the requirement for `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object)` is OK.

The code becomes

```
        var lookup = B.ToLookup(c => c.Time);

        var noMatch = from a in A
                      where !lookup.Contains(a)
                      select a;
```

Comment: On the topic of DataSets: EntityFramework seemed like a lot of work, and Linq to SQL seemed unsuitable. At any rate, I was unsure of how to implement either with an Access DB.

Comment: To read an Access file _fast_, use raw ADO.NET, i.e. DbConnection, DbCommand, DbDataReader. And don't create objects you don't need, don't call .OrderBy() and .ToList() when not needed.

Comment: Was unaware that using raw ADO.NET would provide performance benefits, will bear that in mind :) thank you.

Comment: Is there anything fundamentally wrong with using DataSet/DataTable for holding representations of data? A lot of our legacy code (that has been in use long before I came to this job, I started work here 6 weeks ago) uses it almost exclusively. Would I be right in assuming that a POCO in a Collection with some LINQ manipulation (.Select()) be almost certainly faster?

Comment: @DanPantry That question needs a lot more space than a comment to answer. But in general, there is a fair chance that Linq2SQL is faster than datasets. In the case of the original question, OP is presumably reading an entire table into a dataset, i.e. all rows, all collumns, while all that is really needed is a sequence of dates.

Comment: @DanPantry For more information on Linq To SQL performance, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2007/06/22/dlinq-linq-to-sql-performance-part-1.aspx. Things have only improved since then. Some of this applies to Entity Framework too, but not everything.

Comment: Am OP :P I was reading the entire table into a data set because there were accompanying values - not just the date time, but various values etc that needed to be tagged on (hence Complex object). Thanks for the linq (hehe, puns), should be an interesting read this lunch.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirement then I think this code works well. I've upped it to 6.5m records for both collections and it completes in 11 seconds. Reducing it back down to 650k records takes less than a second.

```
var rnd = new Random();

var xs = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 650000)
    .Select(x => new Complex<int>()
    {
        MyComplex = rnd.Next(0, 100001)
    })
    .ToList();

var ys = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 650000)
    .Select(x => rnd.Next(0, 100001))
    .ToArray();

var xsLookup = xs.ToLookup(x => x.MyComplex);

var newYs = ys.Where(y => !xsLookup[y].Any()).ToArray();

newYs
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(y =>
    {
        xs.Add(new Complex<int>()
        {
            MyComplex = y
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you lists are both ordered by the same key you can loop through both at the same time. Doing this i was able to get the time down to less then that of a `contains` or `except` and even less than the toLookup times i was seeing.

```
var A = SimpleCollection; // source of truth
var B = GetComplexOnDemand().ToArray();
var missing = new List<Complex<DateTime>>();
int cpxIx = 0;
int simpleIx = 0;
while (simpleIx < A.Count)
{
    if (cpxIx >= B.Length)
    {
        missing.Add(new Complex<DateTime>() {InnerValue = A[simpleIx]});
        simpleIx++;
        continue;
    }

    if (A[simpleIx] != B[cpxIx].InnerValue)
    {
        missing.Add(new Complex<DateTime>() {InnerValue = A[simpleIx]});
        simpleIx++;
        continue;
    }

    cpxIx++;
    simpleIx++;
}
```

To Generate the test data i did the following:

```
private static readonly List<DateTime> SimpleCollection = 
    Enumerable.Range(1, SimpleSize).Select(t => new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks + t)).ToList();
public static IEnumerable<Complex<DateTime>> GetComplexOnDemand()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= ComplexSize; i+=2)
    {
        yield return new Complex<DateTime>() { InnerValue = SimpleCollection[i] };
    }
}
```

Comment: I was planning on this but if I'm not incorrect (lack of coffee means this is very likely that I am), this implementation would not deal with missing entries very well.