# Speed improvement in LINQ Where(Array.Contains)

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I initially had a method that contained a LINQ query returning `int[]`, which then got used later in a fashion similar to:

```
int[] result = something.Where(s => previousarray.Contains(s.field));
```

This turned out to be horribly slow, until the first array was retrieved as the native `IQueryable<int>`. It now runs very quickly, but I'm wondering how I'd deal with the situation if I was provided an `int[]` from elsewhere which then had to be used as above.

Is there a way to speed up the query in such cases? Converting to a List doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313010/i-need-to-compare-two-very-large-collections-with-potentially-missing-elements

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In LINQ-SQL, a `Contains` will be converted to a `SELECT ... WHERE field IN(...)` and should be relatively fast.  In LINQ-Objects however, it will call `ICollection<T>.Contains` if the source is an `ICollection<T>`.

When a LINQ-SQL result is treated as an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IQueryable`, you lose the linq provider - i.e., any further operations will be done in memory and not in the database.

**As for why its much slower in memory:**

`Array.Contains()` is an O(n) operation so

```
something.Where(s => previousarray.Contains(s.field));
```

is O(p * s) where *p* is the size of `previousarray` and *s* is the size of `something`.

`HashSet<T>.Contains()` on the other hand is an O(1) operation.  If you first create a hashset, you will see a big improvement on the `.Contains` operation as it will be O(s) instead of O(p * s).

Example:

```
var previousSet = new HashSet<int>(previousarray);
var result = something.Where(s => previousSet.Contains(s.field));
```

Comment: Brilliantly explained Sire!

Comment: This answer saved me from 4 hours to 175ms! Also can use previousarray.ToHashet()

Answer (score 1):

**Where** on Lists/Arrays/IEnumarables etc is O[N] operation. It is O[~1] on **HashSet**. So you should try to use it.